# How to auto charge for my online service using Google Pay

Tags: paypal, billing, recurring-billing, google-pay

I want to make a website, which has a function, users have to login and link their credit card to use that function, and I charge them for how many times they use in a month. Just like how Google does on Google Ads.

How can I do this?

Is this possible by using Google Pay API?

Google Pay FAQ says:

> Support for recurring billing is
>   tied to the payment method returned in the Google Pay API response.
>   Both tokenized cards and cards on file can be used for recurring
>   billing. To process recurring billing, the merchant doesn't have to
>   call our API at a cadence. Rather, the payment credential is stored on
>   the merchant side for recurring payments. The merchant uses their
>   payment gateway APIs to manage recurring billing.
>
> Google Pay supports recurring payments if the following statements are
>   true:
>
> Merchants comply with network rules, such as merchant-initiated
>   transactions. Terms of payment are disclosed and accepted by the user
>   within the merchant’s buyflow. We also support recurring billing with
>   variable amounts. For example, monthly phone bills for mobile carriers
>   are supported. To get more information, merchants must contact their
>   payment gateway representative.

I don't totally understand. Does that mean I have to ask my bank? If so, what data should they give me to accomplish this? Or should I change to other service provider like paypal?

Answer (score 0):

Google Pay doesn't process the payment. It facilitates it by securely providing you (the developer) a payment token that you can use to process a payment with your payment service provider. See [supported payment service providers](https://developers.google.com/pay/api#participating-processors).

What that means is that it depends on whether or not your payment service provider supports recurring payments. Which one are you using?

Braintree for example supports this type of [recurring payment with Google Pay](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/guides/payment-methods/google-pay).