# google pay implementation mvc web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, integration, recurring, google-pay

I am working on an Asp.Net MVC Core project where we want to implement various payment methods. One of them is google pay. I have gone through the javascript SDK for integration. Is it possible to implement recurring payments in google pay? And Can anyone help me where to look fo the docs?

Answer (score 0):

See my previous answer for: [How to auto charge for my online service using Google Pay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61659608/how-to-auto-charge-for-my-online-service-using-google-pay/61664186#61664186)

In short, Google Pay returns a payment credential that you send to your payment provider. The payment credential *can* be used for recurring payments, but your payment provider needs to support it.

Comment: Thank you. And if the provider supports the recurring payments, then how the scheduler works? Does the google pay provide the scheduler or do we need to create a custom scheduler?

Comment: Google Pay doesn't provide this. It will have to be done by either you and/or your payment provider. See [Braintree's documentation](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/guides/payment-methods/google-pay#recurring-billing-and-vaulting) for an example.

Comment: Thank you. I checked the doc. To keep track of the transactions I need to save the payment details to the DB table. For the regular payment, it's not difficult we get response details from the javascript method, but if the payment provider is handling the scheduler then how can we get the response? Can we write any server-side to code to capture the response?

Comment: It's beyond my knowledge unfortunately. You'll need to check with your payment provider.